# how to dismiss alert view after validation?

Tags: ios, swift3, uialertview

I had used `SCLAlertView` used for `forgot password` in this i had placed a `textfield` to enter `email` so that after making successful validation only it need to hide without this it should not hide can anyone help me how to implement this ?

My code is shown below

```
@IBAction func forgetPasswordButton(_ sender: Any) {
        let appearance = SCLAlertView.SCLAppearance(showCloseButton: true)
        let alert = SCLAlertView(appearance: appearance)
        let txt = alert.addTextField("Enter your emailid")
        _ = alert.addButton("Submit", action: {
            let action = txt.text
                print(action as Any)
        })
        if(txt.text?.isEmpty)! == true{

        }else{

        }
        _ = alert.showEdit("Forgot Password", subTitle:"Please enter your email address below.You will receive a link to reset your password",closeButtonTitle: "Cancel")
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the property of `hideView()` and call like

```
let action = txt.text
            print(action as Any)
       alert.hideView() 
    })
```

for more reference you can get the sample [here](https://github.com/vikmeup/SCLAlertView-Swift/issues/277)

Comment: without validation it should not hide i required

Comment: @Thiru - pardon

Comment: bro i am having many doubts on my project can i contact you on your mobile number as mentioned in your profile

Comment: @Thiru - sure my bro

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148580/discussion-between-thiru-and-anbu-karthik).