# Setting capitalization of the first letter on keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I have a button which presents an alert with a text field in it. When clicked on the button it automatically focuses in the text field and keyboard shows. However the letters in the keyboard start as lower-case. How can I fix that so it starts as upper-case?

Edit:

```
alertTextField.autocapitalizationType = .sentences
```

This was what I was looking for.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45310261/swift3-uitextfield-in-uialert-validation-after-button-pressed for an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
let mytextfield = UITextField()
mytextfield.autocapitalizationType = .allCharacters
```

**Other types :**

[image]